# Sbt dependency error with Spark Catalyst and Scala parser library

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

Recently, started learning and using Spark and Scala. Ran into the following dependency conflict issue

**Scala version** : 2.13.8

**SBT version** : 1.6.2

**Spark version required** : 3.2.1

```
[error] (update) found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[error] 
[error]         * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.13:2.1.1 (early-semver) is selected over 1.1.2
[error]             +- ch.epfl.scala:hello-world_2.13:1.0                 (depends on 2.1.1)
[error]             +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.13:3.2.1         (depends on 1.1.2)
[error]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.0"
... other libraries ...

dependencyOverrides += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "2.1.1"
```

Add this `dependencyOverrides` in your build.sbt file